# Secure (plattform independent) char Buffer to std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14

There is a receive buffer of size 8 characters. It is defined, that the received characters are a string. There is no definition (no garantee) that the string is terminated by a zero character.

Simple example:

```
char cBuffer[ 8 ]{ 0 };
ReceiveIncommingMessage( cBuffer );
std::string sStringForFurtherComparison( cBuffer, strlen( cBuffer) );
```

This example will work for for all cases when the received string is less than 8 Byte. I want to catch also the case, where the received string is not terminated by a zero character or is exactly 8 Bytes long.

A `strlen_s( buffer, max_length )` with an max length could solve this issue, so I could make something like this:

```
std::string sStringForFurtherComparison( cBuffer, strlen_s( cBuffer, sizeof( cBuffer ) );
```

I haven't found a function like this in the standard. Is there any elegant solution for this with standard tools? Maybe an oneline?

Comment: Does `ReceiveIncommingMessage` not tell you the message size?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen

Comment: @NathanOliver: No, unfortunatelly I have no information about the size of the received message. I can get only the information that the buffer was filled.

Comment: @MooingDuck That is a C function, not a C++ function.

Comment: A `strlen_s` function exists in `<cstring>` but it was introduced in C11 and is not part of any c++ standard. It seems relatively simple to implement though.

Comment: @ViktorLiehr I found `strlen_s` but it's not a portable solution for c++. If you found a nix specific solution, you can feel free to post it as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make your buffer length 9 (to handle the case where the incoming number of characters is exactly 8 w/o a terminating '\0'), then this works:

```
char cBuffer[ 9 ]{ 0 };
ReceiveIncommingMessage( cBuffer );
std::string sStringForFurtherComparison( cBuffer );
```

The constructor takes a `char *` and the will stop at the first '\0' character.  So this will handle messages of 0 to 8 characters in length.  For reference, that is constructor (5) on this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

I would add that this depends on how much you trust the `ReceiveIncommingMessage` function.

Comment: I have a fixed buffer size, so appending one byte extra and initialize the whole array with zero characters would solve this. Yes :) The best solutions are the simplest. Thx